# Selecting Model for offline speech recognition in Android

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I want to implement CMU Sphinx Speech Recognition Toolkit in my project that is in Android.
For that I want to ask for a demo project that could help me in implementation in my project, also I want to ask which model is being used and how?

Answer (score 1):

> For that I want to ask for a demo project that could help me in implementation in my project

You can find the demo here
http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid

> also i want to ask about the Model that which model is being used and how?

Models are located in assets folder in demo application. You can learn more about models and how are they used in recognition from the tutorial

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorial